# Does the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\log_n n!}{n^3}$ converge?

Tags: calculus

I'm studying for my Calculus-2 Exam by solving old quizzes but I have no idea with this one. Can someone explain in a way that a first year CS student can understand? I tried ratio test, Limit Comparison Test, and direct comparison test.
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\log_n n!}{n^3}$$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Answer (score 4):

You can notice that since $n! \leq n^n$,
$$
\log_n n! \leq n.
$$
Hence,
$$
\frac{\log_n n!}{n^3} \leq \frac{1}{n^2}. 
$$
Therefore
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\log_n n!}{n^3} \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} < \infty. 
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wonder how many problems I have to solve to see the answer this easily.

Comment: Well, it would help in this case to write $n! = n (n+1) \cdots 1$. Then you see that $\log_n n! = \sum_{k=1}^n \log _n k$. So you would like to find a good upper bound on this term so that after diving by $n^3$, you have something which goes to zero sufficiently quickly to ensure convergence of your series. In this case, the crude upper bound $\sum_{k \leq n} \log_n k \leq n \log _n n = n$ sufficed.

Answer (score 4):

You have for all $n\geq2$

$n!<n^n\Leftrightarrow \log_n(n!)<\log_n(n^n)=n$.

This gives the upper bound $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\log_n(n!)}{n^3}<\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$$ which gives the result.